# How to correctly multiply a float with an int and get a result only influenced by significant digits?

Tags: c++, floating-point, multiplication

I have code that converts between a float (representing a second) and an int64 (representing a nanosecond), *taking `6` decimal places from the float*

```
int64_t nanos = f * 1000000000LL;
```

However many decimal values stored in floats cannot be represented exactly in the binary float, so I get results like `14199999488` when my float is `14.2f`. Currently I solve this issue by computing the significant number of digits after the radix point

```
const float logOfSecs = std::log10(f);

int precommaPlaces = 0;
if(logOfSecs > 0) {
   precommaPlaces = std::ceil(logOfSecs);
}

int postcommaPlaces = 7 - precommaPlaces;
if(postcommaPlaces < 0) {
   postcommaPlaces = 0;
}
```

And then printing the float into a string to let Qt round the float correctly. Then I parse the string into a pre and post comma integer and multiple them with integer arithmetic.

```
const QString valueStr = QString::number(f, 'f', postcommaPlaces);
qint64 nanos = 0;
nanos += valueStr.section(".", 0, 0).toLongLong() * 1000000000LL;
if(postcommaPlaces) {
   nanos += valueStr.section(".", 1).toLongLong() * 
     std::pow(10.0, 9 - postcommaPlaces);
}
```

This works fine, but I was wondering whether there is a better, perhaps faster way to do this?

Comment: (double)f * 1000000000LL ?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen that just increases the amount of significant digits, but doesn't completely eliminate it i guess?

Comment: Yes, if f=10.1, the harm has been already done. double d=10.1 OTOH would probably have enough precision for your particular application.

Comment: With 1 year of seconds (31536000 s), multiplied by 1e9 it has 17 significant digits. I don't know whether `double` provides that, but it seems `double` does not :(

Comment: ... but then again, `float` would not have represented the original value either, so then it wouldn't be too bad. but I am interested in any educational explanations that state why/why not I could use double and how i can do it even better.

Comment: `double` has 52+1 significant digits (1 is the implicit bit before the mantissa), and that is not sufficient (it is just shy of 10^16). I must admit I don't quite understand what the question is... given that the original number `14.2` is not representable as a `float`, how would you expect to recover it? How do you expect to differentiate `14.2` from `14.199999488`? I.e. after you have already lost the precision you cannot recover the original number.

Comment: Why do you use float in the first place, when you need precise numbers?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: That won't help, the problem is that the `float` cannot represent `14.2` precisely. The approach above will generate the original `14199999488` result in a different way.

Comment: The main purpose of Qt's rounding code is to make floating-point number look pretty (i.e., 14.2 is prettier than 14.199999488). That's all it does, it doesn't make the number more precise, in fact, it makes the number *less* precise. If the float is 14.199999488, how do you know that it was really 14.2 originally? You don't, and rounding it to 14.2 will lose precision further if the original number was 14.19999925. So the real question is: why do you want your int64 value to be pretty? as opposed to accurate?

Comment: there's a typo: sprintf(temp,"%20.6f",f); and shift 9 left. That should produce the "pretty" number again at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the trick is that I am only interested in 6 decimal places, which a float is able to represent. i am sorry for not having clarified that. I edited the question.

Comment: @JasonD in my understanding it can represent 6 digits, be it pre or post comma *exactly*. The digits may not be 0 if they are 0 in the decimal representation. but they are nearest to it, because in the binary representation they are exact and determined (i.e they are either 0 or 9), not merely the "random" suffix of the result of multiplying the significant digits with the radix base powered to the exponent. Is that understanding wrong?

Comment: So if i add 0.5 to one of those exact/significant digits, i can be sure that it rounds correctly the other significant digits . i.e a "13.99999" becomes a "14.00004".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I get where you're coming from now, I think the wording was/is still a bit unclear. You have >6 decimal digits, scaled by some power of two. There are indeed rules about what happens if you convert back and forward with the same significant digits. What threw me, is saying "my float is 14.2f". Which it can't strictly be. It can be 14.2 to six decimal places, which is what you're trying to extract, but it isn't *actually* 14.2.

Comment: @JasonD yes, I am sorry for my inaccuracy :/

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb the only thing I think you need to be wary of, is that a float can sometimes have *more* than 6 digits of accuracy. In which case, rounding obviously throws away precision. If this is user input, and they're not going to be inputing >6 digits, that perhaps isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to round to one decimal place for example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float f = 14.2f;
    long long n = f * 1000000000LL;
    std::cout << "float: " << n << '\n';
    n = (f + 0.05) * 10;
    n *= 100000000LL;
    std::cout << "rounded: " << n << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

With two decimal places it's `(f + 0.005) * 100`, ...,
and with six decimal places

```
n = ((long long)((f + 0.0000005) * 1000000)) * 1000LL;
```

If you want to consider *significant digits* (all digits), you must first take `log10(f)` and then adjust rounding the *decimal places*.

But as @MarkB already said, if you use `int64_t` in the first place, you don't need this at all.

Comment: +1 for solutions directly to the problem. wish I could do +2.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's not rounding total digits, it's rounding digits after the decimal place. Depending on the magnitude of the original number and the number of digits you're asking for, it may still do the wrong thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you please give an example of where it goes wrong?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If you have 14.199999488 and you round to six decimal places, it will consider 14.199999. If you want to round six total digits, you must consider digits before *and* after the decimal point. This would be 14.1999. It depends on what you're interested in.

Comment: I think, what I got wrong, is the distinction between "significant digit" (all digits) and "decimal place" (digits after decimal point). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, the problem isn't as severe as I first thought because the `f+0.05` expression converts to double. It's still possible though: http://ideone.com/D0dYGp

Comment: I believe that this could also be accomplished maybe a bit more clearly with `long long ns = llround(s * pow(10, decimals)) * pow(10, 9 - decimals);`. Only requires `cmath`.

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh Confirmed! I just tried this with `s=14.2f` and `decimals=6` and it gave `14200000000` as well.

Answer (score 3):

By storing the value in a `float` the damage has already been done, you've lost the original number whatever it was. You can *guess* at a value that might have been intended and then round, or if you're simply trying to display a value for the user you can round to a lower number of decimal places.

Instead, you can solve all these problems by using your fixed-point `int64_t` representation throughout your entire code base, never converting to/from `float` and avoiding throwing away precision during each conversion.

Comment: i do use an int throughout my code base but the float comes from user input :)

Comment: However, if the float indeed results from a scanf, it's not too late, some overkill algorithm could recover a correctly rounded decimal fraction fitting input, unless user entered too many digits... See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, rounding to an arbitrary number of decimal digits is closely related to printing the float. As algorithms which do round correctly are rather complex, the simplest way to do it right is using printf itself.

Note that you don't necessarily have to provide an arbitrary number of digits, an alternative is to use the shortest decimal that would be transformed back unchanged in base 2. Such algorithms are used for printing float in Scheme, Java, Python, Squeak/Pharo, etc ... Unfortunately, neither libm printf nor any standard C library are compliant.

Scheme is even better because it prints * where digits are not significant when you impose a fixed number of digits (* means that any digit would result in same float when converting back in base 2).

In this issue http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=4957 there is an attachment named Float-asMinimalDecimalFraction.st containing an implementation in Smalltalk of similar algorithm for printing than Scheme but that outputs a fraction (the ratio of two arbitrary length integers) rather than an ASCII string.

So, for example, despite 14.2f is represented internally exactly as 14.19999980926513671875 it's not too late, you could retrieve that the shortest decimal fraction which correctly rounds to it is (142/10).

Using such code in Smalltalk, the solution to your problem would trivially be:

```
nanos := (floatingPointSeconds asMinimalDecimalFraction * 1e9) rounded.
```

But above code is using exact arithmetic (`1e9` is an integer) and arbitrary length integers under the hood.

Note that performing the multiplication in float would be bad:

```
nanos := (aFloat * 1e9) asMinimalDecimalFraction rounded.
```

Indeed, though 1e9 asFloat conversion is exact, its significand spans 21 bits, so the float multiplication would most probably cumulate round off errors and worsen the problem of retrieving a short fraction.

Though responding somehow technically to the question, I would personnaly consider above algorithm as pragmatically inappropriate for these reasons:

1. doing it with low level C/C++ instructions without the help of arbitrary precision arithmetic library is not the fastest path to the result
2. it's very limited since it would not apply to the result of computations with several rounding errors (they statistically require many digits)
3. it's overkill if you can simply avoid using a Float at all and work with nanos int

Nonetheless, it's always nice to know that it exists...